# How does wild card pattern matching works in a case expression?

Tags: haskell

I would like to understand an [example server code](https://github.com/jaspervdj/websockets/blob/master/example/server.lhs) which uses the [WebSocket](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets) library.

I've found a strange case expression, which I am not able to understand:

```
case msg of
    _   | not (prefix `T.isPrefixOf` msg) ->
            WS.sendTextData conn ("Wrong announcement" :: Text)

        | any ($ fst client)
            [T.null, T.any isPunctuation, T.any isSpace] ->
                WS.sendTextData conn ("Name cannot " `mappend`
                    "contain punctuation or whitespace, and " `mappend`
                    "cannot be empty" :: Text)

        | clientExists client clients ->
            WS.sendTextData conn ("User already exists" :: Text)

        | otherwise -> flip finally disconnect $ do

        -- ...
```

What does the wild card mean here? The syntax of the case expression is this:

```
case expression of pattern -> result  
                   pattern -> result  
                   pattern -> result  
                   ...
```

Why is the `_` necessary and why is author able to use guards inside it?

Comment: "why is author able to use guards inside it?" Because you can use guards inside of `case` expressions as well as in function definitions, and in this instance it looks like the author just wanted some guards. A nicer (if nonstandard) way to do this is GHC's [MultiWayIf](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if) language extension.

Comment: See also [the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13), which shows that the syntax of case expressions is much richer than what you wrote in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
case irrelevant of
   _ | condition1 -> e1
     | condition2 -> e2
     ...
     | otherwise  -> eO
```

is a fancy way to write a chain of `if then else`.

```
if condition1 
then e1
else if condition2
then e2
...
else eO
```

The `irrelevant` expression is irrelevant. Its value is matched against `_`, which always succeeds and discards the value.

You code confusingly uses `case msg of ...` but `msg` is ignored. Often one writes `case () of ...` so to stress that its value is immaterial.